# How to exclude some indexes in a python loop?

Tags: python, django

I have this list of lists:

```
"data" : [ 
[ 1, "EEBC92F4-DA8C-4B58-8730-3119F6B1C045", 1, 1386882230, "399231", 1386882230, "399231", "{\n}", "2010", "NON-HISPANIC BLACK", "MALE", "HUMAN IMMUNODEFICIENCY VIRUS DISEASE", "297", "5" ], 
[ 2, "84C91A4A-19E2-4AD2-9493-17B84707CA4E", 2, 1386882230, "399231", 1386882230, "399231", "{\n}", "2010", "NON-HISPANIC BLACK", "MALE", "INFLUENZA AND PNEUMONIA", "201", "3" ]]
```

I'm trying to get them like this:

```
for a in list
    for b in a
        print b
```

But of course, I'm getting everything.

I only need the items from the year (2010, 2011) and ahead.

How can I get them?

Comment: What is the year you are refering to?

Comment: you've tagged this django. I suspect that there exists a query or Q_object that will more quickly get you want you want.

Comment: @James, I'm refering about all the information after the year in every row. I'ts not only one row, it's almost 3000 rows. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I'm trying to print a table, each row of the list is a new row in the table. I'm using Django. @NightShadeQueen

Comment: A row already in the table? If so, you should be able to query. What does your model look like?

Comment: I'ts not in a table. It is a .JSON file that's been converted to dict. @NightShadeQueen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = [ [ 1, "EEBC92F4-DA8C-4B58-8730-3119F6B1C045", 1, 1386882230, "399231", 1386882230, "399231", "{\n}", "2010", "NON-HISPANIC BLACK", "MALE", "HUMAN IMMUNODEFICIENCY VIRUS DISEASE", "297", "5" ],
    [ 2, "84C91A4A-19E2-4AD2-9493-17B84707CA4E", 2, 1386882230, "399231", 1386882230, "399231", "{\n}", "2012", "NON-HISPANIC BLACK", "MALE", "INFLUENZA AND PNEUMONIA", "2011", "3" ]]

#get index of the year
l[0].index('2010') #8
l[1].index('2012') #8
```

In case you only want to print you can do:

```
for x in l:
    for el in x[8:]:
        print el
```

which gives you the following output:

```
2010
NON-HISPANIC BLACK
MALE
HUMAN IMMUNODEFICIENCY VIRUS DISEASE
297
5
2012
NON-HISPANIC BLACK
MALE
INFLUENZA AND PNEUMONIA
2011
3
```

Not fully sure whether that is what you want but you wrote that you need all the information after the respective years ("I'm referring about all the information after the year in every row.", your reply to James in the comments) so you could first extract these elements and store them in a new list (in case you want to do something else with them except of printing):

```
lmod = [x[8:] for x in l]
```

`lmod` then looks like this:

```
[['2010',
  'NON-HISPANIC BLACK',
  'MALE',
  'HUMAN IMMUNODEFICIENCY VIRUS DISEASE',
  '297',
  '5'],
 ['2012',
  'NON-HISPANIC BLACK',
  'MALE',
  'INFLUENZA AND PNEUMONIA',
  '2011',
  '3']]
```

This can now be printed as you did it:

```
for sl in lmod:
   for el in sl:
       print el
```

Output:

```
2010
NON-HISPANIC BLACK
MALE
HUMAN IMMUNODEFICIENCY VIRUS DISEASE
297
5
2012
NON-HISPANIC BLACK
MALE
INFLUENZA AND PNEUMONIA
2011
3
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really give a great example, but you can use a generator:

```
filteredList = (x for x in list if int(x[8]) >= 2010)
for a in filteredList:
    for b in a:
        print b
```

Or, you can write it more directly:

```
for a in (x for x in list if int(x[8]) >= 2010):
    for b in a:
        print b
```

Though, you might want your "records" here to be `dict`s instead of lists.

Comment: That's not valid Python syntax, unfortunately.

Comment: You might be thinking of list comprehensions rather than for loops.

Comment: Doh, got confused with generator syntax. Fixed.

Comment: Maybe I needed to be more specific. I'm using a dict that has those lists. See question edit. @rlbond

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in mylist:
    if int(a[8]) > 2009:
        for b in a:
            print b,
        print
```

This goes through each item in `mylist` (renamed from the `list` that masks the built-in), checks if the element at index 8 is greater than 2009, and then prints out the item's elements separated by a single space. If you want more control over the output, use string formatting.